# How to set random value from a set of strings in Batch file?

Tags: arrays, batch-file, random

How to set a random value from a set of strings in a Batch file?

I have some strings in my file like `"You failed!"`, `"Game over!"`, `"OOF!!"` etc.

Is there a way to put them in an array/list and get a random string from that list?

Comment: Try using the value of the system time, with the finest resolution available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that creates an array with 3 values, creates a random number and uses that number to print one of the values:

```
@echo off
REM define list entries
set list[0]="You failed!"
set list[1]="Game over!"
set list[2]="OOF!!"
REM create a random number, smaller than the list's length
set /a randomNum=(%RANDOM%*3/32768)+0
REM print the result
call echo %%list[%randomNum%]%%
```

In this code: `(%RANDOM%*3/32768)+0` the `3` is the max value (exclusive), and `0` is the lowest value (inclusive) for the randomly generated number.